# Obter a média entre datas do tipo timestamp

Tags: postgresql

Possuo 3 datas:

```
2016-08-17 12:29:01
2016-08-17 12:34:13
2016-08-17 12:39:26
```

E gostaria de obter a média de tempo entre elas. Se houver mais de 60 segundos, então em minutos, e o mesmo para horas.

Comment: A ultima menos a primeira divido pelo quantidade de datas é igual a média de tempo entre elas. Certo?

Comment: Eu gostaria de saber a média de tempo das datas. Então seria somar o intervalo de uma data para outra, e dividir. Por exemplo, `2016-08-17 12:39:26` - `2016-08-17 12:34:13` = `00:05:14` e `2016-08-17 12:34:13` - `2016-08-17 12:29:01` = `00:05:12`. Portanto (`00:05:14` + `00:05:12`) / `qdteDatas - 1`. Acho que da no mesmo, porém a variável é a qdteDatas, ao invés de utilizar 2 datas (primeira e  última) @ReginaldoRigo

Comment: Você quer fazer em uma linguagem específica ou somente usando sql?

Comment: Postgresql mesmo @CleidimarViana

Comment: Acredito que, se ter algo que faça o cast em milisegundos, faça a operação matemática de média, e retorne o cast para data. Se quiser, mais tarde eu gravo como resposta pra ver se funciona.

Comment: É isso mesmo. A soma do tempo entre elas e igual a diferença do tempo entre a primeira e a ultima. Portanto não tem mistério.

Comment: Este [link](https://battisti.wordpress.com/2008/12/10/calcular-diferenca-em-timestamp-no-postgres/) pode te ajudar um pouco.

Answer (score 3):

Segue uma solução utilizando `window functions`:

```
SELECT
    cadastro.data AS data,
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM cadastro.data) - lag(EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM cadastro.data)) OVER (order by cadastro.data) AS intervalo
FROM
    ( SELECT unnest( ARRAY[  '2016-08-17 12:29:01'::timestamp, '2016-08-17 12:34:13'::timestamp, '2016-08-17 12:39:26'::timestamp ] ) as data) as cadastro
```

Saída:

```
'2016-08-17 12:29:01';<NULL>
'2016-08-17 12:34:13';312
'2016-08-17 12:39:26';313
```

**Referência:**

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html

Comment: Considerando que as datas são encontradas em uma tabela `cadastro` e um campo chamada `data`, como ficaria ?

Comment: @Jonathan: `SELECT cad.data AS data, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM cad.data) - lag(EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM cad.data)) OVER (order by cad.data) AS intervalo FROM cadastro AS c;`

Comment: Cara, não funcionou aqui. Esses `data` refere-se ao campo ou ao alias ? @Lacobus

Answer (score 0):

Subtraia a menor data da maior e divida pela contagem de linhas - 1:

```
with cadastro (data) as ( values
    ('2016-08-17 12:29:01'::timestamp),
    ('2016-08-17 12:34:13'),
    ('2016-08-17 12:39:26')
)
select (max(data) - min(data)) / (count(*) - 1) as média
from cadastro
;
   média    
------------
 00:05:12.5
```

O resultado é do tipo `intervalo`